# I want the moment when a Key is "Down" in the PreviewKeyDown Event in WPF

Tags: wpf, handle, preview, skip, routedevent

when I jump into the PreviewKeyDown the char righthand to the Caret in my RichTextBox is not moved YET. I would like to say to this event do your stuff move the char to the rightside and THEN let me do MY stuff. How can I do that?

```
private void RTB_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
 {
    if (e.Key == Key.Space)
    {
       // event do your stuff

       // Char righthanded from the Caret position is moved to the right side

       // do MY stuff
    }

}
```

UPDATE: that you know what I talk about... =>

[image]

The Caret was directly before the Word "Harold..." then I pressed the spacebar key several times to move the "Harold..." to the right. But the formatting a black Underline seem to be stuck... how can I make the Underline stay attached to the Run object containing the name "Harold..." ?

The reason why I wanted to catch the spacebar key in the KeyDown event is to get the new implicit created Run-object and remove the black Underline.

Answer (score 1):

"Preview" events are fired before the event happens. There will be an equivalent `KeyDown` event that is fired after the event is processed. Wire up to that event instead and your code will run after WPF has completed handling the keypress.

Comment: It is more difficult... The problem is when I subscribe to the KeyDown event the spacebar key is not recognized, but I want to do special stuff only for the spacebar...

Answer (score 0):

That is why its called PreviewKeyDown... the event you want is probably KeyDown or TextChanged